# How get an alert message on element load?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, alert

I want to get an alert message after popup load.
It workes on the body tag but doesn't respond in this div.

```js
<script>
        function myFunction() {
          alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="modal fade flat-popupform" id="popup_10_jan" onload="myFunction()">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/images/events/jan-10-2019/1.jpeg" alt="Events" style="max-width:100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `onload` into `<body>` ?

Comment: yes i did but i want on pop up load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onload event attribute does not work on a div tag.

The only supported tags are `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>`

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp to learn more.

The easiest solution I can think of is to simply put the script tag and the javascript code (inside the script tag) right after the div.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade flat-popupform" id="popup_10_jan">
    <script>
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    </script>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/images/events/jan-10-2019/1.jpeg" alt="Events" style="max-width:100%;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The script should execute right after the div loads, since it is inside the div. That should solve your problem.

Comment: but this is still work on load page event not on popup load.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. I just fixed the problem in which your `myFunction()` wouldn't work `onload`. What do you mean by popup load

Comment: this div re-present a pop box,after click this pop up box shown ,i want that first this popup box 's div load and than script alert message shown.

Comment: In that case, what you can do is (assuming you're using jQuery .click), you can show the alert message inside the .click function.